# Допустимо ли использовать выражение «услуги бизнесу»?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли, допустимо ли использовать выражение «услуги бизнесу»?

Услуги для бизнеса – понятно, правильная фраза. А ее сокращённый вариант?